# Create a static Haskell Linux executable

Tags: linux, haskell, libraries, static-linking, ld

It's not often two things I love so much come together to cause me so much annoyance (besides my kids). I've written a Haskell program at work that uses libraries like text, xml-enumerator, attoparsec-text, etc. I have it working properly on my Windows machine at work, my Ubuntu virtual machine at work (32-bit), my Ubuntu desktop (32-bit again) and an EC2 instance running Ubuntu (64-bit).

Our client is running CentOS 5.3, 64-bit. I can't for the life of me get this executable to run properly. I tried creating a static executable using:

```
ghc --make myprog.hs -optl-static -optl-pthread
```

But when I try to run that executable on the CentOS server, I get an error message:

```
openFile: invalid argument (Invalid argument)
```

I'm assuming this is related to [the bug described here](http://biohaskell.org/Installation). I've tried compiling from both 32 and 64 bit Ubuntu, tried static and shared builds, nothing works (though I occasionally get segfaults instead of the above error message). I can try downloading CentOS 5.3 and creating a virtual machine for it, but it will take a while to download, and I'm not sure which version of GHC will work on it (I tried getting GHC 7 on their server, but I ran into a libc issue).

At this point, I've come up with a few possible approaches, but I'd like to avoid these if at all possible:

- Rewrite in a different language (the thought of doing this in Java makes me queasy, though it could be a nice time to try out Cal/OpenQuark).
- Maybe try out an alternate compiler, like jhc. But I'm not quite certain how to get started installing all the dependencies for this program in jhc; if people have experience and know that text/attoparsec/etc work in jhc, I'd love to hear it.
- Hack of all hacks: build a Windows executable, install wine on their server and run it that way.

As a total aside, these are the situations where I *really* wish we had a JVM backend for GHC. I suppose I could try out LambdaVM as well. But I'd love to hear community advice on what to do here.

Comment: If you're distributing to them in the future, then making a CentOS 5.3 VM is definitely a good idea. And it may be the hack of all hacks, but if it works under wine, that could save you a lot of time and heartache.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This simple example "works for me":

```
$ cat A.hs
main = print "yes"

$ ghc -O2 --make -static -optc-static -optl-static A.hs -fvia-C -optl-pthread

$ ldd A
    not a dynamic executable
$ ./A
"yes"
```

(and I've used this process, via .cabal, to ship executables for clients in the past couple of years).

I think the best bet is to file bugs, and get this working. The IHG can also fund work like this, but I'm fairly sure the GHC team would consider this a high priority, if you're trying to ship products.

Comment: I'll try that out tomorrow, I hadn't thought of the -fvia-C or -optc-static options. In general I would file bug reports for this, but I have *incredibly* limited access to their server, so I can really provide full debug information.

Comment: Since you have all the static libraries necessary, this works very well. (on my system I did need to compile additionally the libgmp and libffi)

Comment: So what do these options actually do?

Answer (score 8):

It is related to the old glibc library in CentOS. You have to compile with the same version of glibc as installed on CentOS.

I had exactly the same problem. Haskell executable compiled on arch (or ubuntu) won't run on CentOS. In my case though i was lucky, because our admin just removed CentOS and installed Arch for application server.

Answer (score 6):

I found out the problem. It seems that the link to the Biohaskell page is accurate: this is a problem loading iconv. This occurs when calling `openFile`, but *not* when calling `openBinaryFile`. Since `xml-enumerator` uses the latter, it worked just fine. Switching over the rest of the code to use `openBinaryFile` instead (via `Data.Enumerator.Binary.enumFile`) got everything to work.

This is a good workaround for my use case, but the bug still exists.