# Haskell binary compatibility

Tags: haskell, static-linking, binary-compatibility

Let's say I write some Haskell code and compile it in an Ubuntu 64-bit installation, statically linking all Haskell packages and c libraries. Would the result be binary compatible with any other 64-bit linux distribution?

Comment: It should be, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10549484/477476 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/5953787/477476

Comment: Wow, the binary that results from `ghc -02 test.hs -optl-static -optl-pthread` is about 2.5GB (test.hs contains `main = print "yes"`).

Comment: actually 2.5MB. Someone can't read `ls` output haha

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because of the static linking - it is all in the binary. And yes, they can get quite big, for example a yesod output can easily alot to 70MB. Yet, it has a HTTP server within that 70 MB.

So, static linking can thus help portability, but has it's drawbacks in terms of executable file size.